# Not able to debug my c++ code in visual studio code

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code, terminal

I don't what happened to my vscode all of a sudden I am not able to debug files although I am to run my CPP program but not able to debug please help me I spend 2-3 hours continuously trying to fix my debugger

my program is running fine and compiler is creating a exe file as shown below
[image]

when I hit the debug button this image appears
[image]

and then it stuck on this screen
[image]

when I press any kind of key it exits and the normal terminal window appears
[image]

it is just like it is trying to open the external terminal but not able to open it some how this is what i think spending a whole day solving this problem

Lauch.json file

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++.exe - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

Task.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Looks like you have Visual Studio Code, not Visual Studio. If this is your intent, carry on with the question. If you wanted to use Visual Studio, you got the wrong download, I'm afraid.  [Here's the right one](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/)

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What happens when you try to debug?

Comment: You will have to give us more information on what happens and what steps you have done to try to figure out why. Your config files look fine.

Comment: Maybe you unwittingly activated the option that automatically closes the execution window when the program ends? Try setting a breakpoint somewhere in your code and see if you can reach it, that will narrow down the potential issues. And by the way, you have an [amusing typo](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/poop) on "pops up"  ;)

Comment: @kuroineko no bro that doesn't work i don't know what happen all of a sudden day before yesterday it was working absolutely fine and yesterday when i tried to debug a simple program it just didn't run at all

Comment: You have my sympathy, but how are we supposed to help if you don't provide more specific information? All we see is an IDE in the process of building an executable, with no apparent problem. We don't know if the build succeeded, if the IDE tried to start a debugging session, and, assuming the IDE went that far, what happened to your executable (an early exit, an exception...).

Comment: @AlanBirtles bro i have updated post now see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting the

1. %USERPROFILE%.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.6.0-insiders\install.lock
2. %USERPROFILE%.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.6.0-insiders\debugAdapters

worked for me. Windows 10

for more information Please see: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/7971

Answer (score 0):

Try add `-g` to flags. -g is flag to enable debugging.